# How to git config cherry-pick -Xignore-all-space as default for Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

To preface I use both Git and Gerrit at my day job. A common workflow is to cherry-pick a patchset under review, resolve any conflicts with the merge, and then make more changes and amend the commit before pushing a new patch set back up to Gerrit.

I've found that git cherry-pick has a hard time dealing with trivial whitespace changes by default and that using the merge strategy option of -Xignore-all-space often significantly reduces the amount of conflicts that need to be resolved during a cherry-pick of a patch set. I want this to always be the default behavior during a cherry-pick without having to specify the option but haven't found a way to set this up in .gitconfig

The obvious workaround solution is to simply make an alias for Git however when using Gerrit there is a convenient cherry-pick command that can be copied to the clipboard with the click of a button which takes the following form:

`git fetch ssh://user@hosturl:port/remote/repo/path refs/changes/id/change/patch-set && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD`

Needing to replace the "cherry-pick" portion with an alias is equally as inconvenient as needing to add the "-Xignore-all-space" option as I am doing now. Manually typing that verbose fetch for the Gerrit patch set reference is absurd and I don't have the ability to change the Gerrit project or anything not local to my machine unfortunately.

Is there a way to git config a default cherry-pick merge strategy option or perhaps a way to use a hook script or trigger to accomplish this?

Comment: Is "refs/changes/id/change/patch-set" literal, or is it some dynamic name?

Comment: Dynamic. As is the first part depending what project, branch, change, and patch set you want to fetch off gerrit.

Comment: Where are you entering the command?

Comment: Maybe you should address the root of the problem. The white spaces. We had the same issues as well (C++) and we now automatically format our code using [uncrusitfy](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) I would almost say this is one of the most important things you need to do to be able to cherry-pick changes across branches and save yourself a lot of work

Comment: @uncletall ironically use of an automated plugin (codemaid) is what is causing so many conflicts as indentation and white space errors get fixed in existing source.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss I use Console2 to run Git bash ... hmmm good idea, perhaps some creative use of sed in an alias that could be bound to a shortcut would work well enough

Comment: @AJG85 We also use codemaid. Indeed you should not cleanup as you change code as this introduces unrelated white space changes but do a one time off cleanup of the whole code base. We did it one day when we made sure most pending reviews were closed. We ran the cleanup. After that we have no more issues with white spaces as during review we make sure all spacing is correct. If white space errors did get in the code base we make a separate commit to clean this, not combined with any other changes.

Comment: That is the final conclusion I came to and ended up submitting a massive formatting patch for our primary module. If I'm making changes in another team's component I just flip the codemaid switch off before saving source where as in my code it's nice a pretty ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this in a bash-compatible shell would be to add an alias
`alias git-cp='git cherry-pick -Xignore-all-space'`
Add that to your .bashrc and source ~/.bashrc done.

One caveat to keep in mind: no white space allowed in the alias name.

Comment: See paragraph three. I'm an evil Windows user who prefers to use a mouse to enter my git commands in one or two clicks ;-)

Comment: I'm slowly being converted as there is apparently some things you can't easily drive from a gui.